# Filter based on min and max

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe as follows

```
Calls   Weight 
  R       1
  A       1 
  S       3 
  S       3
  Q       7
  W       5
  E       9
```

If I have a min of 3 and a max of 5.

I am trying to filter the data so that all values below less than 3 are filtered out.
While all values greater than 5 are changed to the max (which is 5)

Expected output:

```
     Calls   Weight 
      S       3 
      S       3
      Q       5
      W       5
      E       5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformation is straightforward:

```
df = df[df.Weight >= 3]
df[df.Weight >= 5] = 5
```